# Question about memory and subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, memory, memory-management

I was wondering if a view created with IB which can disappear from the main view (translation to the +2000 to x with an animation for exemple) take more memory if it is added always on the subviews of if I have to `removeFromSuperview` it each time it disappear from the view and `addSubview` when I want make appear it.

Regards,
KL94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but I wouldn't count on it. To hide the view, set the `.hidden = YES` property. That would be your best bet to lower memory consumption while keeping the view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think the property hidden change something with memory, I guess it only set alpha view to make it transparent.

Comment: @kl94 I don't think so. Really hiding a view means that the UI doesn't even bother to render the contents, so there is no need for a pixel buffer. Setting alpha to zero might do the same, but moving the view off-screen still requires the UI to have a look at the contents of the view to see if it may have some unclipped content.

Comment: Ok I agree with you but you are talking about performance, But I search a way to keep most memory as possible even if both are linked.

Comment: @kl94 the memory consumption of a UIView object probably doesn't depend really on the `superview` property being set and/or the size of the `subviews` array. The object itself isn't that big of a deal either (but you could redesign your app so that the objects only exist when visible). The big killer is the buffer containing the pixel data, on which the view is drawn.

Comment: well, you seem to be sure of you, more than me anyway. Thx for explanations.